# SQL Connection issues where UDL works

Tags: sql, windows, vb.net

First I want to thank you for reading this issue and for any support or help you can give.

The problem I'm encountering is that on a Windows 10 PC which is on a network, I can connect to a SQL Server using the Microsoft Data Link (.udl) but the same connection string in my VB code won't connect. I feel like I'm missing something but I don't know what that is.

I am doing some pro-bono work for a charity to help them move from paper-based records towards an IT solution.

I've created software in VB .Net which is based on a client-server approach to SQL Server. The entire thing works pretty good on my PC where both the software and the SQL Server reside.

The charity's IT support is outsourced and my experience of working with them has been disappointing. They're pretty good when it comes to Windows but profess to have no knowledge of SQL Server. My own experience of setting up SQL Server is limited but sufficient to get it working.

The Charity's network is fairly well locked down. For example, I can't run software 'As Administrator'. This can only be done by IT Admin.

Currently, on the SQL Server I have the following set up:

- The windows user logon can access the server
- The windows user logon is mapped to a database user
- A SQL Logon has been created for the server
- The SQL Logon is mapped to a(nother) database user

I can access the SQL Server through SSMS on the Charity's PC using either of the logons above.

Using Microsoft's Data Link (.udl) I can successfully connect to the database (ergo: the server) using either of the Connection Strings below.

Below are the connection strings which work in the Data Link

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=aaaa;Initial Catalog=dbName;Data Source=SQLServerInstance
```

Code:

```
    Public Shared initConnString As String = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=master;Data Source="
    Public Shared connString As String = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=dbName;Data Source="
```

The Data Link will connect with either of the above. I've only used the Integrated Security=SSPI strings in the code. The SQL Server instance gets appended to the connection string before use. In the software which works on my PC, the connection fails.

As I have to re-write some of the code to take account of the network security settings (i.e. not using Registry to store settings and configuration) I'm wondering if there's anything I am missing in trying to get the connection to the SQL Server working in the software on the Charity's PC? In setup configuration software I've written, I'm thinking of having the software iterate through the connection options in a preferential order (Windows Authentication first then SQL Login) and stopping at the first one which works and setting this as the connection string? Is this what you'd recommend?

I'm taking it that Windows Authentication on SQL Server is better than Mixed Mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a mixed mode authentication server? If so, any of the following should work

Windows Authentication

```
Server=<Name or ip address of server>;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=<name of your database>
```

SQL Server authentication

```
Server=<Name or ip address of server>;User Id=<user id>;Password=<password>;Database=<name of your database>
```

You may also add other connection string attributes like Connection Timeout, etc.

Also make sure that in your SQL Server Configuration Manager, Named Pipes and/or TCP/IP are enabled. You can enable one or both.

So in your code, you can do it like this (whichever connection string you use):

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Server=<Name or ip address of server>;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=<name of your database>"
Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
```

You can now then use your connection instance

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had but tbh, I had to set up the SQL Server on my own. I've enabled TCP but I don't think I've enabled Named Pipes. I'll review when I'm back there. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: If you enabled TCP then you have to use the server's IP address. Also make sure that remote connections is enabled in SQL Server. And check the server's firewall. Allow SQL Server's port